# Combine 2 tables into 1 (shared common column)

Tags: sql

I believe my problem appeared somewhere on this site (of course they are resolved) but those solutions did not work for my case.

I have:

**Table 1**

```
isbn | in_count
123  |     3
124  |     1
```

**Table 2**

```
isbn | out_count
125  |     1
126  |     1
```

**My expected result:**

```
isbn | in_count | out_count
123  |     3    |     0
124  |     1    |     0
125  |     0    |     1
126  |     0    |     1
```

I've tried with the sql:

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT o.isbn, COUNT(*) AS out_count FROM out_tbl o GROUP BY o.isbn) t1
FULL OUTER JOIN
(SELECT i.isbn, COUNT(*) AS in_count FROM in_tbl i GROUP BY i.isbn) t2
ON t1.isbn = t2.isbn;
```

But what I got in return was:

```
isbn | in_count | isbn | out_count
123  |     3    | null |   null
124  |     1    | null |   null
null |   null   | 125  |    1
null |   null   | 126  |    1
```

Please help with this. Really appreciate!

Comment: I tried with "....FROM out_tbl o"  but you did not share what is in "out_tbl" ?  (Same for "in_tbl").  But you shared "Table 1" and "Table 2" , and not using them..... Should we start guessing?

Comment: @Luuk Yes, I got a typo, table 1 is out_tbl and table 2 is in_tbl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT T.isbn,T.in_count,0 AS out_count
FROM TABLE_1 AS T
UNION ALL
SELECT X.isbn,0,X.out_count
FROM TABLE_2 AS X
```